# How to use wildcards in Makefile targets/dependencies for files that are generated at runtime?

Tags: makefile, wildcard, gnu-make, unzip, target

I'm working on a data science project in which I'd like to set up the training data folder using GNU Make. This involves preprocessing a large number (>10k) of audio files stored in a zip file. I would like to write a Makefile that fetches a zip file from the internet, unzips all of the .aiff files, converts them to .wav using ffmpeg, and then removes the .aiff files. I'm struggling with how to create targets/dependencies for files that won't exist until some other rule is executed and generates them. Here is my toy example:

```
.PHONY: dataset
DATA_DIR = data

dataset: ${DATA_DIR}/train/%.wav
    @echo Dataset built!

${DATA_DIR}/train/%.wav: ${DATA_DIR}/train/%.aiff
    ffmpeg -i $*.aiff $*.wav; rm $*.aiff

${DATA_DIR}/train/%.aiff: ${DATA_DIR}/data.zip
    unzip $< data/train/*.aiff

${DATA_DIR}/data.zip:
    # ... download the zip file and place it in ./data...
```

The rule for downloading and unzipping the .aiff files works fine, but when it gets to the conversion with ffmpeg it fails.

```
  ...
  inflating: data/train/train9997.aiff
  inflating: data/train/train9998.aiff
  inflating: data/train/train9999.aiff
ffmpeg -i %.aiff %.wav; rm %.aiff
ffmpeg version 4.2.7-0ubuntu0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-nvenc --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
%.aiff: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '%.aiff': No such file or directory
```

I think I'm not using `%` correctly. It appears to be expanded before the files are generated. I'm not sure if I'm supposed to use `$(wildcard ...)` or `.SECONDEXPANSION:` or some other arcane Make magic in order to generate an arbitrary number of .wav targets from an arbitrary number of .aiff dependencies in the folder they are stored in relative to the Makefile. I cannot pre-declare these files in a variable because there are so many of them (and let's say for argument's sake that I don't know the total number or names of all the files, just their extension). I want Make to figure out the dependencies and their targets at runtime after the files have been unzipped.

**Is it possible to do this in Make? If so, how do I do this?**

**EDIT:**
Note I was "sort of" successful using a different approach, but this approach violates the recommendation to not use directories as targets. And I was hoping it would be possible to set as targets the actual files to be extracted from the zip file. Thanks.

```
dataset: ${DATA_DIR}/train
    @echo Dataset built!

${DATA_DIR}/train: ${DATA_DIR}/data.zip
    unzip $< "data/train/*.aiff"
    for f in $@/*.aiff; do ffmpeg -i "$${f}" "$${f%.aiff}.wav"; rm "$${f}"; done

${DATA_DIR}/data.zip:
    # ... download the zip file and place it in ./data...
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "you can't do that".  Make works in two distinct phases: first it reads the makefile and constructs a graph of targets and prerequisites.  Then it walks the graph and builds things.  Once the first phase is complete, you can't go back and add more targets to it.  Only through  pattern rule matching can that happen.

But this:

```
dataset: ${DATA_DIR}/train/%.wav
        @echo Dataset built!
```

is not a pattern rule.  A pattern rule MUST have a pattern matching character (`%`) in the *target* name.  If there's no pattern char in the target it's just a normal explicit rule so this rule says that `dataset` has a prerequisite of the literal filename `data/train/%.wav`, so that's what make tries to build.

There are many ways to do what you want but the simplest one is just to use recursive make.  The parent make will extract the file and the sub-make (which has a completely different graph) will examine the already-available content.  Like this:

```
.PHONY: dataset
DATA_DIR = data

# This target is the parent make
dataset: ${DATA_DIR}/data.zip
        $(MAKE) build-wav
        @echo Dataset built!

${DATA_DIR}/data.zip:
        # ... download the zip file and place it in ./data...  

AIFF_FILES := $(wildcard ${DATA_DIR}/train/*.aiff)

# This target is invoked in the sub-make
.PHONY: build-wav
build-wav: $(AIFF_FILES:.aiff=.wav)

${DATA_DIR}/train/%.wav: ${DATA_DIR}/train/%.aiff
        ffmpeg -i $< $@
```

Comment: This definitely demystifies things, thanks. I now understand that it needs to be run in two stages. However I still couldn't get your solution to work. It downloads the data, but doesn't run the recipe that performs the unzip action. Here's the make output after the file downloads:
```
make build-wav
echo Dataset built!
make[1]: Entering directory '/path/to/Makefile'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'build-wav'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/path/to/Makefile'
Dataset built!
```

Comment: Oh sorry, I got it wrong.  I fixed it.  Note I removed the `rm` of the .aiff file.  I don't know why you want to do that; it doesn't seem like a good idea to me.

Comment: Thanks, for responding. I tried your approach but still get the error message mentioned in my previous comment. I noticed that your solution doesn't actually extract the .aiff files from the zip file. Shouldn't that be part of the target/dependency chain in either the main recipe or sub make? Shouldn't there be a target for all those aiff files to be created by unzipping them from the zip target?

Comment: Also: I edited my original post so you can see my previous attempt a solution (which does work but is bad practice, imo, especially since one change in the folder will cause all of those wav files to be rebuilt instead of just the one who's source aiff has changed).

Comment: I assumed that the target that "downloaded" the file also unzipped it but I see that your comment doesn't really say that.  Well, there's no way this makefile can work the way you had it originally because make has to be able to compute up front what the files are that it wants to build.  How can make know what files to build, if the source files exist only in the zip file?  IOW, you can't have a rule that only extracts each file you want to build from the zip file, when there's no way to know what you want to build until after you've extracted the zip file.

Comment: My makefile was assuming that the `data.zip` target would BOTH download AND unzip the entire contents of the zip file.

Comment: I added the the unzip to the recipe and everything unzips but that's not the problem. The problem appears to occur after that, when the submake is called. I still get the same error message:
`make build-wav`   `echo Dataset built!`   `make[1]: Entering directory '/path/to/Makefile'`   `make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'build-wav'.`   `make[1]: Leaving directory`   `'/path/to/Makefile' Dataset built!`

Comment: That means that your wildcard is not expanding properly.  Double-check the paths involved.  Make sure that the `AIFF_FILES` variable (when you are in the sub-make) is finding the files that were unpacked from the zip file.

Comment: Is there some kind of debug or echo statement I can put in to check how `AIFF_FILES` and the various targets/dependencies are being expanded? To me the paths look correct. The Makefile sits in the parent directory of `${DATA_DIR}` and so far as I can tell, all `aiff` files are being unzipped to `${DATA_DIR}/train/*.aiff`. (Thanks for your help, btw, really appreciate the effort)

Comment: Sure, just write `$(info value of $(AIFF_FILES))` anywhere you want in the makefile; expansion of the `$(info ...)` function follows the same rules as expansion of variables.